# Type universe cannot resolve assembly in WP7 project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

```
System.Reflection.Adds.UnresolvedAssemblyException
Type universe cannot resolve assembly: System,
Version=2.0.0.0,
Culture=neutral,...
```

I just updated to Mango and the 7.1 SDK and newest Silverlight Tool kit.

I have tried deleting and re-adding this reference, but I still get this error in design mode for a xaml page.

This looks like a really simple and stupid error on my part. Not sure what I should try next.

Also, it's not an issue with unblocking a DLL, since as you can see, it's System.dll.

Any ideas as to the root cause would be appreciated.

Comment: Post the code.  The fact the type is lowercase means its not a Microsoft class.

Comment: it's not at compile time. It's at design time. It's the XAML throwing this, which is even more annoying. It compiles fine. I don't know what code i could post to help.

Comment: could this be related to using a 7.0 solution on a 7.1 sdk? Or some mismatch there? I use some third party libraries like Telerik and the Silverlight toolkit.

Comment: Any progress on finding a solution to this? I've got the exact same issue...

Comment: nothing yet. i've trolled the MSDN forums and google. some say it's changes to the way you write certain xaml. I've had nothing but problems since I upgraded to 7.1. a lot of my code doesn't work anymore.

Comment: can you zip up and post the whole solution somewhere so we could try it out? I can't make this happen on my machine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a reference I had added that was seemingly causing this. I can't tell if it was the Facebook C# SDK or the IsolatedStorageExplorer library. Perhaps they aren't up to date with Mango, it's the only thought.

Either way, I'm a little frustrated at the vague nature of the error and how it blows up in the XAML and not the code. I feel like the IDE should know where the error is coming and help you with a better stack trace. At this time, the only way to figure this stuff out is process of elimination. Delete all, add back one by one.

I appreciate the help!

Comment: There may be an easier way than trial and error when the issue is in the designer. It involves a second instance of visual studio as mentioned in the answers for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453173/debug-visual-studio-or-blend-silverlight-wpf-designer-load-errors

Answer (score 1):

@Rajeev Nair (and all other with a similar error)

I also had the error with the System.Data assembly.
For me it was a reference to 'System.Data.SqlServerCe'. After removing the reference it worked.

I even didn't make any use of the assembly, just referenced it in the project. 
So if you get a similar error, check your referenced 3rd party assemblies (even if you don't use it in your code).

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed I get this answer after downloading components from the Internet. I **have** to unblock them first, before I add them as references. More details can be found in [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6472515/633267)

Answer (score 0):

The similar error occured to me, but for System.Data assembly. I think this was due to the system.data.linq reference I added. I removed the reference and added again. The error disappeared and I could load the screen in the designer. The error is misleading for sure.